# To obtain the diameters of the maximum and minimum circles using specific (x,y) points on the coordinate plane

Tags: python, geometry, least-squares, measurement, subpixel

I have the coordinates of the circular edge regions on a picture, in the form of (x, y). Using these points I am able to subtract the mean circle using least squares and measure its diameter.

```
import numpy as np
import circle-fit as cf

coordinates = np.stack((edges.x, edges.y), axis=-1)  #Stacking the x and y coordinates.

xc,yc,r,_ = cf.least_squares_circle((coordinates))   #Finding the average diameter.
```

r: radius

xc: center point (x-axis)

yc: center point (y-axis)

But I also need the diameters of the maximum and minimum circles passing over these points. How can I find? Thanks.

[image]

[image]